# Spark job in cluster is very slow ("executor computing time" increases for each task)

Tags: apache-spark

Usecase : We have collection of small documents to be analysed.

Spark setup : Spark1.5 with standalone cluster, 2 worker nodes with 8 core each and 10GB memory each.

Program :
1)Documents are loaded into `List<Tuple2<Doc_Name, Doc_Contents>>`
2)parallelizePairs is invoked with above collection and partition size is set to 100.
3)Map() - Each document is analysed and then a json is generated.
4)collect()

Issue : 
For tasks that are scheduled first(task 0 to 16), "executor computing time" is around 3 mins, but for tasks that are scheduled later "executor computing time" increase each time(8 mins, 12 mins and 17 mins).[Here is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAAIY.png)

Observation:
When i run the code in local mode, each task takes same amount and everything works fine. When same code is excuted in standalone cluster mode, each task becomes slower and slower as shown the screenshot. I did try client and cluster deploy mode, in both cases when the application in executed in standalone cluster, "Executor Computing Time" increases for subsequent tasks.

Sample Code:

```
List<Tuple2<String, String>> data = getData(); -> data is around 7MB
JavaPairRDD<String, String> pairRDD = sc.parallelizePairs(data, 100);
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> aRDD = resumePairRDD.map(new ProcessDoc());
List<Tuple2<String, String>> output = aRDD.collect();

public class ProcessDoc implements Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple2<String, String>>, Serializable {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, String> call(Tuple2<String, String> fileNameContentTuple) throws Exception {
    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileNameContentTuple._1());
    String content = fileNameContentTuple._2();
     // Below API has dependency on many other classes and approximately takes around 2 seconds for each record.
     DocumentAnalyzerResponse documentAnalyzerResponse = DocumentAnalyzerFactory.parse(content);
     String resultJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(documentAnalyzerResponse);
     // Upload the resultJson to s3
    }
}
```

Thanks for all comments.

Comment: What do you do with this data once you call collect()?

Comment: Please post the spark-defaults.conf. Also check if you are using the garbage collector, if not then the job will eventually die. Also after collect() if you don't require that data, the RDD should be unpersisted

Comment: Can you post the actual code? It's much easier for us to help if we know exactly what you have written (that way we can also test it ourselves). Also are the loaded documents comparable in size?